# Confusion on Quantum Harmonic Oscillator Eigenvalues

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, mathematics, differential-equations

In standard PDE theory, one generates eigenvalues to Sturm-Liouville problems over a finite domain. So, for a wave equation, we have an infinite number of eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ for a Dirichlet problem, say.

What is the mathematical justification for having an infinite number of energy eigenvalues for the quantum harmonic oscillator? The eigenfunctions are Hermite functions, but over the **infinite** domain, $-\infty < x < \infty$. Is there some existence theorem that guarantees this discrete set of eigenvalues even on an infinite domain?

Comment: Random spit-balling here, but the square-integrability requirement may allow you to restore the consequences lost to expanding the domain.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @dmckee I suspect that the more likely suspect is the fact that the potential is unbounded at spatial infinity. Only bound states in QM have discrete spectra.

Comment: not an expert, could it have to do with the fact that the eigenfunctions of the harmonic oscillator are Schwartz functions, and smooth compact support functions are dense in Schwartz functions?